# How to package icons inside a Blazor (razor) component

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I am creating a login component that I plan to deploy on nuget and consume in various Blazor apps. How do I package the icons I am using (open-iconic) inside the component? Is this even possible? Or am I supposed to download the dependencies in the consuming app?

Comment: Yes, you make a RCL with assets in the wwwroot folder https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#create-an-rcl-with-static-assets

Comment: RCLs produce a netcore project which is not compatible with Blazor Client which is a netstandard project. I have been successful with producing a netstandard component project and consuming it as reference/nuget in my blazor project. The problem is the component's CSS and icons are not coming over.